# Django Apache setup - forbidden Error 403

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

Since it did not work on the first time, I created a fresh new venv for my django project.

my folder structure looks like this: btw I used the Django/Apache Setup guide from digitalOcean (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04)

/home/pi/myproject/myprojectenv (this is where my env is located)
/home/pi/myproject/myprojectenv/myproject/myproject (this is where the settings.py is located)

I added this to the settings.py file (I use a pi, I only serve locally)

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

and at the bottom

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

my /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


        #for django
        Alias /static /home/pi/myproject/myprojectenv/myproject
        <Directory /home/pi/myproject/myprojectenv/myproject/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/pi/myproject/myprojectenv/myproject>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/pi/myproject/myprojectenv python-path=/home/pi/myproject
        WSGIProcessGroup myproject
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pi/myproject/myprojectenv/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py



        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

       

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        
</VirtualHost>
```

when I go to /static in the browser I get a http 403 forbidden Error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your alias is wrong

```
Alias /static/ /home/pi/myproject/myprojectenv/myproject/static/
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but this did not change anything at all. Let me know if you need further information on my setup, pretty lost rn

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd remove (if you haven't already) the DocumentRoot from your configuration, since you don't seem to be using that feature. [See here.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html#:%7E:text=UserDir-,DocumentRoot,-In%20deciding%20what)

Where are your static files? If they're in `BASE_DIR/static/`, your alias is wrong, as Mohamed has pointed out. And remember to include the last forward slash, so use `/static/` instead of `/static`.

Also, if you have a static file, let's say `BASE_DIR/static/css/styles.css`, you would access this through `http://localhost/static/css/styles.css`, so make sure you're using the appropriate URL.

Last but not least, is your site working properly besides apache not serving static files?

Comment: Could you take a look at this post and suggest something to check? thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73263626/django-served-with-apache-how-to-set-pythonpath